# Configuring Play! Framework to show full stack trace

Tags: java, playframework, stack-trace

Is there a way to configure [Play!](http://www.playframework.org/) to show a full stack trace on error on the dev error page?

The default exception view is very nice, but useless if one uses stuff like [Preconditions](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html).

I understand you can get it via the log, but it would be nice to see it on the dev error page.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, full stacktrace is always shown to log. You can even define a different format for your log files by using log4.properties.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question to specifically getting it to display on the error page.

Answer (score -1):

One way that I know is to look at console output - full stacktrace is always there.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question to specifically getting it to display on the error page.

Comment: That's not what I'm seeing -- I'm not getting full stack traces in the console

Comment: I also do not get a full stacktrace in the console when using `activator run`.